# Effect of feeder length in microstrip patch antenna

Tags: antenna, microwave, microstrip

**Summary of the question :** Why reflection coefficent changes with microstrip feeder line length ?

**Explanation of the question:**

I'm working on re-simulating this paper : [Microstrip Patch Antenna Array Design](http://www.emo.org.tr/ekler/a192d45c5262f9f_ek.pdf)

The model and simulation done but claimed S11 parameters did not matched with the simulation. Here first picture is design from conference paper and second picture is the version with longer feeder line. [Internet search like this](https://www.researchgate.net/post/how_to_select_the_length_of_the_feed_line_in_patch_antenna) claims that feeder length does change anything, just width and thickness is important. But as seen in third image, (blue curve is for short feeder length and red curve is for long feeder), it has very big effect on reflection. It may be mistakes on the conference paper or something else but I want to learn why the feeder length has effect on S11 parameters. Any explanation or reference would be great.

Thanks in advance !

**Design Parameters :**

Substrate : 1.6mm thick, FR-4 with epsilon_r = 4.3

Conductor : 0.035mm thick, Copper(Annealed)

Ground Plane : 0.035mm thick copper

Frequency : 4GHz

Simulated with CST Studio Suite, Frequency Domain Solver

[image: Design in Reference Paper]
[image: Design with longer feeder]
[image]

*Note that there are some changes on patch size but they are out of the question, they only effect center frequency and my question is valid for this situation too. (I simulated without changing patch sizes and S11 parameter still changed with length of microstrip feeder line)

Comment: Does the basic antenna impedance at your required centre frequency entirely match the characteristic impedance of the feeder line?

Comment: @Andy aka Hi, it's been some time I tried to optimize it and find a reason, So far I think they are not entirely match, theoretical calculation results 85.86 ohm line impedance but I don't know a way to find basic antenna impedance (I assume you mean the impedance at the edge of patch). I guess the answer of my question is :
 Because of the unmatching, the feeder line should has lambda/4 length so it can act as quarter wavelength impedance matching line. ++

Comment: ++But I'm not sure because in conference paper they claimed they achieved around -40dB s11 parameters with short feeder length(10.8mm) by keeping all other parameters same. If anyone has real explanation with theoretical calculations please write it as answer and I'll accept it as an correct answer.

Comment: Not really - you need to ensure that the antenna impedance matches the feed line or the impedance seen at the other end of the feedline won't be 50 ohm (or your reference impedance).